# UIButton state is '5' when touchDown

Tags: uibutton

I have a custom button where I set the background and text colour for normal state and reverse them on selected state. I am facing following issue.

1. When button is in normal state, on touchDown event button moves to 'highlighted' state (integer value 1) which is expected.
2. When button is in selected state, on touchDown event button moves to state 5 (I am logging the state). I cannot find what this value corresponds to. This changes the text colour to same as background colour and hence the text becomes invisible until the button is pressed.

Can anyone tell me what is this state '5'?

Answer (score 4):

It's the bit mask state for UIControlStateSelected|UIControlStateHighlighted